# 404 ошибка при запросе к api в android приложении

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest, cordova, apk

Настраиваю api для своего приложения которое создаю на vue js и потом монтирую через cordova в apk и ipa. Создал для теста на удаленном сайте php файл обработчик который принимает запросы (пока простые чисто для теста) и выдает ответ. такого содержания acore.php:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
 header("Content-type: application/json; charset: utf-8");;
 $v['id'] ='11'; $v['nn']='22';
 echo json_encode($v);
```

а вот так уже в приложении я посылаю туда запрос:

```
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', 'http://www.****.com/hyst/acore.php', false);

            request.onload = function() { 
              if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
              var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
              alert(data.id);
              } else {
              alert(request.status+' error');
              }
            };
            request.send();
```

Проблема в том что, когда тестирую приложение в разобранном виде в браузере - всё работает, **запрос уходит и ответ возвращается ко мне**, но **после того как собираю всё это cordova в apk** и устанавливаю на телефон и пробую там, мне **выдает 404 error алвертом** который я прописал выше.

так же тестировал на указывая это сервис https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
та же самая история, что наталкивает на мысль что дело в самой, кордове, что при сборке надо выствалять у самого приложения какие то разрешения на html запросы к сторонним сайтам
подскажите кто знает как это решить?
вот что у меня стоит в config.xml в корне приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Ну вот и ответик на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360244/xmlhttprequest-failed-on-app?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @Total Pusher спасибо! работает!) у меня к вам предложение вы сейчас возьмете и напишете тут тот же ответ что и там только на русском) Я смогу пометить его как правильный - вам плюс, у меня будет хороший процент отвеченых вопросов, и самое главное если у кого то возникнет такая же проблема, но они не так хорошо дружат с английским как я они без напрягов всё тут увидят) потому что вопрос очень важный, а информации по нему в сети просто так найти слжно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cordova (одна из базовых платформ Ionic) ограничивает запросы только локальными ресурсами (`file: //`), что приводит к 404-ошибке всех внешних запросов.

Чтобы исправить это поведение, вам нужно использовать [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) и настроить его под свой API.

Делается это так.

Сначала добавьте плагин в проект:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

Затем добавьте свой API в белый список в файле `config.xml`:

```
<allow-intent href="*://*api.parse.com/*"/>
```

[Оригинал ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30360244/xmlhttprequest-failed-on-app?answertab=active#tab-top)